# question about jacobi sums and equation $x^n+y^n=1$

Tags: number-theory, quadratic-residues

I’m trying to follow the book A Classical Introduction to Modern Number Theory byIreland and Rosen, but I have a couple of question about two proofs, so I will write down some parts of the proofs, showing where I have doubts, hope you can help me

A multiplicative character on $F_p$ is a map $\chi$ from $F_p^*$ to the nonzero complex numbers that satisfies
$$\chi(ab)=\chi(a)\chi(b)$$
for all $a,b \in F_p^*$

Let $\chi, \lambda$ be characters of $F_p$ and set
$J(\chi, \lambda) = \sum_{a+b=1} \chi (a)\lambda(b)$

**First question (first part of section 4 page 98)**
Suppose we have the following, for $p\equiv 1 \pmod n$
$$N(x^n+y^n=1) = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} \sum_{i=0}^{n-1}J(\chi^j,\chi^i)$$
so we want to estimate the sum. So, when $i=j=0$ we have $J(\chi^0,\chi^0)=J(\epsilon,\epsilon) =p$. When $j+i=n$, we have that $\chi^j=(\chi^j)^{-1}$**(why?)**, so that $J(\chi^j,\chi^i) = -\chi^j(-1)$. The sum of these terms is $-\sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \chi^{j}(-1)$. $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\chi^j(-1)$ is $n$ when $-1$ is an $n$th power and zero otherwise. Thus the contribution of these terms is $1-\delta_n(-1)n$ where $d_n{-1}$ has te obvious meaning.**(why the sum is $n$ when $-1$ is and $n$th power)**. Finally, if $i=0$ and $j\neq 0$ or $i\neq 0$ and $j=0$, then $J(\chi^i,\chi^j)=0$. Thus
$$N(x^n+y^n=1) = p + 1-\delta_n(-1)n + \sum_{i,j}J(\chi^i,\chi^j)$$
**(how do we get this last equality or expression?)**

**Second question(section 5 proposition 8.5.1 part (b) page 99)**
Assume that $\chi_1,\chi_2,\ldots,\chi_s$  are nontrivial and that $\chi_{s+1}=\chi_{s+2} = \cdots = \chi_l = \epsilon.$ Then
$$\sum_{t_1+\cdots +t_l=0} \chi_1(t_1)\chi_2(t_2)\cdots \chi_l(t_l) = \sum_{t_1,t_2,\ldots,t_{l-1}} \chi_1(t_1)\chi_2(t_2)\cdots \chi_l(t_s)$$

**(why is this equality or expression true?)**

Thank you in advance

Comment: Did you show the Gauss sum (discrete Fourier transform) [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_sum) $J(\chi,\psi) = \sum_{a=0}^{p-1} \chi(a) \psi(1-a) = \frac{g(\chi)g(\psi)}{g(\chi \psi)}$ ?

Comment: @user1952009 yeah

Answer (score 0):

**First question:**

i) When, $j+i=n$, we have that $\chi^j=\chi^{n}\chi^{-i}=\varepsilon \cdot\chi^{-i}=\chi^{-n+j}=\chi^{-n}\chi^{j}=-\varepsilon \cdot \chi^{j}=(\chi^j)^{-1}$.

ii) When $-1$ is a $n^{th}$ power, then there exists $a \in \mathbb{F}_p$ such that $a^n=-1$. As $\chi$ is a character of order $n$, $\chi(-1)=\chi(a^n)=\chi^n(a)=\varepsilon(a)=1$. If $-1$ is not an $n^{th}$ power, then suppose $\chi(-1)=x$. Then,$\chi^n(-1)=x^n=1$ (since $\chi$ is of order $n$). It follows that
$$-\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}\chi^j(-1)=-\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}x^j=-(x^{n-1}+x^{n-2}+\ldots+x+1)=-\frac{x^n-1}{x-1}=0.$$

**Second question:**

There's a little typo in your question, it actually is $$\sum_{t_1+\cdots +t_l=0} \chi_1(t_1)\chi_2(t_2)\cdots \chi_l(t_l) = \sum_{t_1,t_2,...,t_{l-1}} \chi_1(t_1)\chi_2(t_2)\cdots \chi_s(t_s).$$

Then, as $t_l$ is determined as $t_l=-(t_1+\ldots+t_{l-1})$, we have

\begin{align*}
\sum_{t_1+\cdots t_l=0} \chi_1(t_1)\cdots \chi_l(t_l)&=\sum_{t_1,\cdots t_l}\chi_1(t_1)\cdots \chi_s(t_s)\chi_{s+1}(t_{s+1})\cdots \chi_{l-1}(t_{l-1})\chi_{l}(-(t_1+\ldots+t_{l-1}))\\
&=\sum_{t_1,\cdots t_l}\chi_1(t_1)\cdots \chi_s(t_s)\varepsilon(t_{s+1})\cdots \varepsilon(-(t_1+\ldots+t_{l-1}))\\
&=\sum_{t_1,t_2,...,t_{l-1}} \chi_1(t_1)\chi_2(t_2)\cdots \chi_s(t_s).
\end{align*}